# Should I assume sender can be null?

Tags: c#, resharper

Should I assume a `sender` (of a CLR event handler) or a `d` (of a dependency event handler) be `null` and write some code for the case? Or can I simply mark them as `[NotNull]` and ignore warnings?

I'm using VS2019 + ReShaper to build a C# project. When "Value Analysis Mode" of R# is set to "Pessimistic (an entity is assumed when it doesn't have explicit `NotNull` attribute)", it warns `sender` and `d` can be `null`.

```cs
//// R# warns sender can be null.
private void OnSomethingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //// Should I throw an Exception when sender is null?
    //// Or can I simply mark sender as [NotNull]?
}

//// R# warns d can be null.
private static void (DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    //// Should I throw an Exception when d is null?
    //// Or can I simply mark d as [NotNull]?
}
```

Comment: It's possible some code will call the method directly and pass in a null, always code defensively - check for nulls!

Comment: I think its best practice to always check if something is null, here is a question where the dependency object is null https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281898/dependencypropertys-value-is-null-when-method-in-attached-propertys-class-is-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone recommend me that I check an object be null. So, IMO, this would be the best practice in case I'd like to utilize `sender` (or `d`) in the method.

```
    private void OnSomethingHappened([CanBeNull]object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!(sender is MyClass mc)) throw new ArgumentException();

        mc.DoSomething();        
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Now I prefer this:

```
    private void OnSomethingHappened([CanBeNull]object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var mc = sender as MyClass ?? throw new ArgumentException();

        mc.DoSomething();        
    }
```

Comment: I recommend following approach: `var x = sender as MyClass; if(x == null)...`

Answer (score 0):

It always safe to write null checks:

```
if(objectThatShouldNotBeNull == null)
{
  AppropriateAction();
  // if necessary
  return;
}
```

Generally, if it used later in code, IMO it has to be checked for `null` value.

Especially when sometimes you, or other developers, might want to call this method from code (I do that sometimes - then I follow abocve pattern) and set `sender` to `null`.

Comment: Thanks, Based on this answer, I posted what I think is the best practice. What do you think of it?